# Looping with a random number generator in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have a random number generator here that picks a number from 1 - 50.

What I want it to do is pick a second random number from 1-50, that will *only* print to the console if it is greater than the previous random number, and repeat a number of times, let's say 10 times.

My teacher wants me to use only the Math.floor(Math.random() method to generate a number so I have to work with that.

I'm not sure how to compare the latest generated number to the previous generated number.

What I got so far is

```
int myRand = 10;
    while (myRand > 0) {
        int myRand2 = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
        System.out.println(myRand2);
        System.out.println();
        myRand--;
```

Where would the second part that would compare that first generated number to subsequent generated numbers go?

Comment: Please have a look at the `Random` class. Not only is it clearer to fetch an integer value using `nextInt()`, you also circumvent many pitfalls and avoid casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by picking a random number:

```
int randomNumber = pick();
```

Now you need to pick another one

```
int otherRandomNumber = pick();
```

and print it to the console if it's bigger than the previous one

```
if (otherRandomNumber > randomNumber) {
    System.out.println(otherRandomNumber);
}
```

But you need to do that 10 times, so you need a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

And, at the end of each iteration, the "other", latest random number becomes the previous one of the next iteration, so let's rename variables and assemble all this:

```
int previousRandomNumber = pick();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int otherRandomNumber = pick();

    if (otherRandomNumber > previousRandomNumber) {
        System.out.println(otherRandomNumber);
    }

    previousRandomNumber = otherRandomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it clear. I guess I have an issue with 'while' as I was unsure where I should put the counter that ends the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your first variable `myRand` is not random... To me it looks more like your loop iterator. You are never making two random variables. If I understand your question correctly, your answer should look more like this:

```
int i = 10;
while (i > 0)
{
    int myRand1 = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    int myRand2 = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    if (myRand2 > myRand1)
        System.out.println(myRand2);

    System.out.println();
    i--;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't tell by the question, but if you want the first random number to be chosen only once, then declare it outside of the loop.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped the question a bit there. It's that counter at the end that kept messing me up.